# add temporary markers on google map v2 android

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using google maps v2 API on an android application and i want to know how to add temporary markers to the map, for example add a marker that will disappear 10 minutes after adding it.

Comment: When should it not disappear? After finishing `Activity` or rotating the device?

Comment: after a certain period of time